# resource interpreted as stylesheet but transferred with mime type text plain issue?

Tags: css, apache, resources

I am working in Apache 2.2. My localhost opened my web page, but there is no CSS applied and background images were not loaded. I don't know why. Using the Chrome developers tool I got the following warnings:

```
resource interpreted as stylesheet but transferred with mime type text plain 
resource interpreted as stylesheet but transferred with mime type text html
resource interpreted as script but transferred with mime type text html
GET http://www.xmweb.com/js/calendar/layout-3d.css 404 (Not Found)
resource interpreted as Image but transferred with mime type text html
```

I do not understand this issue. Is it a problem in the httpd.conf file? I tried to add a .htaccess file, but still I got the same issue. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If seems that your browser cannot load the CSS, and you are getting a 404 (Not found) and a HTML page with a 404 message. Try to load http://www.xmweb.com/js/calendar/layout-3d.css directly via your browser and look at the page.

It may help to open up the error log of your webserver to see whats missing.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with a stylesheet, and I solved it by adding this line to the .htaccess file:

```
AddType text/css .css
```

I would try this and also make corresponding entries for javascript and images.