# Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with mime

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Fellow Coders,

I am having this error in my website when i uploaded it to my FTP: Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/plain

```
</head>
<body>
    <div class= "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">BlahBlahism</a>

            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target= ".navHeaderCollapse">
                <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
            </button>   
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="Responsive.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
        <div class="container">
            <p id="pcolor">BlahBlahism | © Copyright </p>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Here are my scripts

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="responsive.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-3/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="bootstrap-3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [resource interpreted as stylesheet but transferred with mime type text plain issue?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347102/resource-interpreted-as-stylesheet-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text-plain-iss)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OP forgot to upload his `responsive.css`, and it wasn't found. Ensure you have uploaded that file to the root folder.

As shown below, you can see if this is happening in the network tab (F12 in firefox or chrome under the developer tools). You can also click on the `mystyle.css`, and click "Response" to view what was downloaded and ensure you're seeing the correct stylesheet.

[image]

If you navigated to the css file, you would see that it goes to your hosting providers 404 error page, instead of the correct .css file.

Comment: I just added a comment that i closed a tag :D but thanks for the feedback

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of the error you're encountering? What isn't loading? Is it a specific script? What happens when you view: source, and you attempt to click on the links. Do the files exist?

Comment: The files etc. Open normally. But the background image isn't showing at all. www.kayelderen.url.ph is my website. The responsive.html

Comment: That's because `responsive.css` can't be found. Ensure you have uploaded that file to the root folder. If you clicked on it, you would see that it goes to your hosting providers 404 error page, instead of a `.css` file.